# How to disable radio button overwrite?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have second thing on my page:
In array (`Completed` is bool):

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Options[i].Completed)
```

As html this looks like

```
<td>
    Yes 
    <div id="Options_0__Completed-styler" class="jq-radio" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
        <input id="Options_0__Completed" name="Options[0].Completed" type="radio" value="True" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; opacity: 0; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
        <div class="jq-radio__div"></div>
    </div>
    No
    <div id="Options_0__Completed-styler" class="jq-radio checked" unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
        <input checked="checked" id="Options_0__Completed" name="Options[0].Completed" type="radio" value="False" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; opacity: 0; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
        <div class="jq-radio__div"></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

My issue is that potentialy, because of jq-radio (comes from jquery.formstyler.js) I can't do any change for radio buttons.

For example:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        var test = $('input[name="Options[' + i + '].Completed"]').filter('[value=False]');
        test.attr('disabled', true);
    }
```

If I look on html, then I will see that input with value False is disabled, **BUT** visually, nothing changes for be.

How can I fix this kind of issue?

Comment: You should use `prop()` instead of `attr()` when setting Boolean values. `test.prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: Not making any difference. I tried `Attr`, `test.prop('disabled', true)`, even `test.disabled = true`. Nothing happened.

Comment: This is clearly a issue with the `jquery.formstyler.js` plugin you are using. It hides the radio buttons then generates its own html but looking at the js file, it does not appear to have any functions to manipulate or update its own html based on the underlying value of the input (which makes it a poor plugin so you should look at an alternative)